# How to set angular2 ie9 shim?

Tags: angular

I want to make a web site compatible with IE9.
After reading below documents, I added a polyfill script in index.html.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

However, there is a 404 NOT FOUND error as I expected. (because there are no routes for node_modules)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) shim.min.js
Here is a error screenshot:
[image]

I think there are more preparations for this setting.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show a proper error displayed?

Comment: did you install it: `npm install core-js`

Comment: yes, I installed it. (I created my project by angular CLI, and CLI installed core-js. I has confirmed it from package.json > dependencies > "core-js": "^2.4.1")

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the angular's tutorial app structure then you will get to know that from where the index page is getting served, there is no `node_module` folder.

Instead you have to get up one level `../` and change to this:

```
<script src="../node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I understand your comment. However I think there is no more parent from index.html, because index.html is in the root folder. Anyway I can fix this problem by moving shim.min.js to the root folder. (for temporary expedient) But, when I build this project by "ng bulid --prod" and run it from /dist folder, it still produce same error. Do I always have to copy & paste shim.min.js file to deply this project??

Comment: @changsoo yes! as this might not be included in the build process so you have to serve it either statically, from some CDN if available or put it in the build process so that it would be available in the bundle.

Comment: I also have found that I can import shim.min.js in src/polyfills.ts. (e.g: import 'core-js/client/shim.min.js') If I include shim.min.js in polyfills.ts this way, I think I don't need to copy & paste or download from CDN. (Of course including polyfills may be redundant for mordern lastest browsers) Anyway, Is this a right way to include polyfills? If I goes wrong, please correct me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! that is also correct. as you haven't mentioned about structure so i didn't included it in the comment and in answer as well.

Comment: Hi guys, any idea if the order is important when including the shim in polyfills.ts? the shim also seem to be breaking on Safari on iOS 9.3, its complaining about the toString() prototype...